# Another Rails 3 Nested Forms Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have the following:

```
class ComplexAssertion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assertion_groups
  has_many :assertions, :through => :assertion_group

class AssertionGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :complex_assertion
  has_many :assertions, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave=>true

class Assertion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assertion_group
```

And my form looks like the following:

```
<%= form_for(@complex_assertion) do |f| %>
<div class="childGroup1" style="padding:5px;">
      <%= f.fields_for :assertion_groups do |assertion_group_fields| %>
      <%= assertion_group_fields.fields_for :assertions do |assertion_fields| %>
      Type: <%= assertion_fields.collection_select :assertion_type_id, AssertionType.all, :id, :name %>
      Attribute: <%= assertion_fields.collection_select :attribute_name, Attribute.find_by_sql("select distinct a.name from attributes a "), :name, :name %>
      <%= assertion_fields.label :operator_type_id %>: <%= assertion_fields.collection_select :operator_type_id, OperatorType.all, :id, :value %>
      Value: <%= assertion_fields.text_field :value, :size=>'1' %>
      <% end %>
          <div id="innerOperator">
            <!--OPERATOR BETWEEN EACH ASSERTION IN A GROUP-->
            <%= assertion_group_fields.collection_select :logical_operator_type_id, LogicalOperatorType.all, :id, :value %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div id="createComplex" align="center">
       <%= f.submit :value=>'Submit' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

When I try to save, I get the following error:

```
AssertionGroup(#48180276) expected, got Array(#19330344)

Rails.root: C:/Eagle6/Assertions

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/complex_assertions_controller.rb:43:in `new'
app/controllers/complex_assertions_controller.rb:43:in `create'
```

I've tried to make multiple changes to get this to work correctly, but I think I'm missing some very fundamental piece of logic here.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I was under the impression that if I got the Models done correctly and used the Form_builders, that Rails would handle the inserts and relationships.

Thanks!

Added controller code - very vanilla.

```
def create
@complex_assertion = ComplexAssertion.new(params[:complex_assertion])
respond_to do |format|
  if @complex_assertion.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@complex_assertion, :notice => 'Complex assertion was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @complex_assertion, :status => :created, :location => @complex_assertion }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @complex_assertion.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Adding your controller code would be helpful in this case, as that's where your stack trace is pointing to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ComplexAssertion` class should look like this

```
class ComplexAssertion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assertion_groups
  has_many :assertions, :through => :assertion_group

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assertion_groups # <= add this
```

Your `AssertionGroup` class should look like this

```
class AssertionGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :complex_assertion
  has_many :assertions, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave=>true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assertions # <= add this
```

You can find more about this at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html ("Nested attributes examples", "One-to-many").

Comment: After adding that line, I restarted my server, submitted the form and got the error:
    unknown attribute: assertion_group

Comment: It's going to be really difficult to help you without any code or stack trace, but your assertion groups accept fields for assertions. In the interest of clarity, I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Please. let me know what you need. I'll gladly put it here.

Comment: I've changed my Models to have exactly what you put above.  When I do that, no forms are written for this block: <%= f.fields_for :assertion_groups do |assertion_group_fields| %>  I don't see any errors, just no form for the :assertion_groups and then obviously for the :assertions

Comment: Just so I'm clear:  ONE Complex_Assertion HAS MANY Assertion_Groups - with a Complex_Assertion_ID in the Assertion_Groups Table.  Then, Assertion_Groups is made up of Assertions with an Assertion_ID in the Assertion_Groups Table.  Maybe my ORM thinking is backwards.   BUT...the form should create a new Complex_Assertion that contains Groups and Groups contain Assertions.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood you, your classes don't properly map to your DB schema. Since AssertionGroup `has_many :assertions` and Assertion `belongs_to :assertion_group`, you should have a `assertion_group_id` attribute in the assertions table, not the other way around. This is a good place to learn more about ActiveRecord associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs_to-association

Comment: Yeah, I think you're correct.  I'm going to scrap it and start over, creating the step-down relationships instead of a 'bridge-table' type relationship.  Thanks for your input!